# What are the valid characters for a Java method name?

Tags: java, methods, naming, rules

I read about the [naming of Java variables](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/variables.html). It says that Java variables cannot start with any numbers and special characters except for $ and _.

Some valid examples:

```
int count;
int _count;
int $count;
```

And some invalid examples:

```
int %count;
int 4count;
int #count;
```

Do the same rules apply to method names?

Comment: Is there a reason why you'd want to use characters like these at the start of a variable, method, or anything?

Comment: I'm working on an extern domain specific language with Xtext that is executed on Java virtual machine. That's why I would like to make this precise :) Thanks!

Comment: possible duplicate of [Legal identifiers in Java](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11774099/legal-identifiers-in-java) because of http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-8.html#jls-8.4

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Yes, method names and variable names are what's called "identifiers". Identifiers all share the same rules regarding accepted characters. Take a look at [§3.8](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-3.html#jls-3.8) from the Java Language Specification to find out exactly what an identifier may contain, and [§6.2](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-6.html#jls-6.2) for an explanation about how identifiers are used.

Comment: Yes, and this is a nice view of it here, too. http://cui.unige.ch/isi/bnf/JAVA/identifier.html

Answer (score 1):

You might be surprised when having unusual characters for method, such as:

```
public void mój_brzuch_zacznie_burczeć()
```

and it works pretty nice. Take a look at [this blog](https://thomassundberg.wordpress.com/2015/01/30/bdd-with-cucumber-jvm-at-geecon-tdd-2015/) to see more fancy examples.

Comment: or U+02BC (Modifier Letter Apostrophe)
`void itʼs_a_method()`. You can use any modifier letters https://unicode-table.com/en/blocks/spacing-modifier-letters/

Answer (score 0):

From the Java Tutorial:

"Although a method name can be any legal identifier, code conventions restrict method names."
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/methods.html