# Can Enums in Java have names with inequality signs?

Tags: java, enums

I'm new to Java and trying to setup a switch statement using enums. for the declaration of my enums however I am getting compilation errors such as "illegal start of type", so my question is if names such as  are appropriate?

```
public enum Types
{
 <CD>, <Title>
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, [enum constants](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-8.html#jls-8.9.1), like all Java [identifiers](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-3.html#jls-3.8), must start with a letter, a currency character ($), or a connecting character (most common being `_`).

Comment: [Interesting question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/11774099/758280) on valid Java identifiers.

Comment: Ummm ... you should NOT use the $ character in identifiers in your source code.  They are technically legal, but the JLS states that $ is reserved for use by compilers, generators and so on.