# Is int π; is valid syntax in java?

Tags: java, unicode, identifier

I have some doubt ,i want to know that is int π; is a valid syntax in Java Or Not because Java support UNICODE so according to me it can be valid but I want to make sure

Comment: syntax for what, identifiers ?

Comment: Did you try it? And **why not**? Also even if it is valid _syntactically_, it is not wise because of the _semantics_ to use an `int` with the name `π`. As you might have heard of it, `π` is a mathemathical constant...

Comment: Should surely be **double** π? Unless you want to redefine it as 3 or something. ;)

Comment: Yes, its a valid syntax.

reffer this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12857340/naming-restrictions-of-variables-in-java

Comment: Yes it's a valid variable name.

[Refference link][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12857340/naming-restrictions-of-variables-in-java

Comment: Yes it's a valid variable name.

[Refference link][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12857340/naming-restrictions-of-variables-in-java

Answer (score 7):

`int π;` is perfectly valid - as you say Java supports unicode so anything not reserved is fair game for identifiers.

Comment: Still, I would be careful about using 'weird' characters in method names that you expose. Some unit testing frameworks, for example, can freak out about that. Just be careful...

Comment: `double π;` is even better, if you do not want to loose precision and do not want to aggravate the mathematicians around you...

Comment: @CostisAivalis except that a `double` ofcourse also is not infinitely precise, so that it cannot contain the exact value of π.

Comment: @Jesper Hahahahaha!!!! That's right!

Comment: `π` is valid because it's a letter and identifiers may start with a letter, not solely because java supports unicode. `♟` cannot be used in identifiers for example even though it's unicode and not reserved.