# How to sanitize user input for Java-generated code?

Tags: java, security, code-generation, code-injection, sanitization

Having a function that generates Java code in a textual form (something similar to a template-engine, if you will), how would you sanitize user-provided fields to prevent code injection?

For instances, if I'm using a template similar to:

```
void function_${user_provided_function_name}() {
    // Do stuff
};
```

And the user provides as input `(){System.exit(0);}; void function_dummy`, the generated code would be:

```
void function_(){System.exit(0);}; void function_dummy() {
    // Do stuff
};
```

Even if I'm tempted just to not allow parenthesis (to prevent function calls), this seems highly fragile.

Comment: You could check that the provided String is [a valid identifier](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12857340/naming-restrictions-of-variables-in-java).

Comment: I wouldn't. This approach to safely running user-supplied source code is misguided. You need to run it in a security sandbox such that only a whitelisted set of objects and methods are available. Look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1715036/how-do-i-create-a-java-sandbox

Answer (score 1):

If you want to *validate* user input (as is) to make your code compilable, you have to make three checks to `user_provided_function_name`:

- Lexical check: It must be a valid Java identifier: starts by letter, dollar `$` or underline `_`, and then zero or more ocurrences of letter, dollar, underline or digit.
- Sintactical check: It must not be a Java keyword: `for`, `while`, `class`, `abstract`, `void`, etc.
- Semantical check: It must not be a method from `java.lang.Object`: `toString`, `notify`, `getClass`, etc (neither a not-overridable method from its superclass).

To accomplish the first rule, a regular expression could do it. A single Set would do for the other two rules.

But if you are willing even to modify the user input, you must first make it a valid Java identifier by deleting all the wrong characters according the first rule above, and then apply the other two rules.