# How to validate if a string would be a valid java variable?

Tags: java, regex

How can I best check if a string input would be a valid java variable for coding? I'm sure I'm not the first one who is willing to do this. But maybe I'm missing the right keyword to find something useful.

Best would probably be a RegEx, which checks that:

- starts with a letter
- can then contain digits, letters
- can contain some special characters, like '_' (which?)
- may not contain a whitespace separator

Comment: I'm wondering why you need that...

Comment: @JanDvorak: Automatic code generation (or validation)?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11774099/legal-identifiers-in-java

Comment: Jan: That's a completely different question.

Comment: I've reopened this, because the apparent duplicate was not, in fact, a duplicate.

Comment: If your are using Java 6+, consider `javax.lang.model.SourceVersion` class. It has methods for such stuff.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

```
public static boolean isValidJavaIdentifier(String s) {
    if (s.isEmpty()) {
        return false;
    }
    if (!Character.isJavaIdentifierStart(s.charAt(0))) {
        return false;
    }
    for (int i = 1; i < s.length(); i++) {
        if (!Character.isJavaIdentifierPart(s.charAt(i))) {
            return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
}
```

EDIT: and, as @Joey indicates, you should also filter out keywords and reserved words.

Comment: You're missing keywords, `true`, `false` and `null`. They have to be disallowed. But yes, otherwise that's exactly what the spec suggests ;-)

Comment: Oh yes, that's true. There are plenty of other keywords as well.

Comment: Not that many: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-3.html#jls-3.9

Comment: might want to have a null check and an extra `)` on the first if. also a `_` in the string would trip the code up as it doesn't have a second character

Comment: That gets me started in a nice direction. Keywords check are not so important as of now for my case, but probably easy to extend with the link provided.

Comment: @eis: I consider it a bug to pass null to such a method, so an NPE is what I want here. I don't understand the second part of your comment: _ is a valid Java identifier.

Comment: @JBNizet yes, was just thinking that the for loop looks for char at index 1 on the first iteration, which wouldn't exist on `_`. But I guess for loop condition check is done before the first iteration, too.

Answer (score 16):

### Java 6+

Use

```java
import javax.lang.model.SourceVersion;

boolean isValidVariableName(CharSequence name) {
    return SourceVersion.isIdentifier(name) && !SourceVersion.isKeyword(name);
}
```

if you need to check whether a string is a valid Java variable name in the **latest** version of Java or

```java
import javax.lang.model.SourceVersion;

boolean isValidVariableNameInVersion(CharSequence name, SourceVersion version) {
    return SourceVersion.isIdentifier(name) && !SourceVersion.isKeyword(name, version);
}
```

if you need to check whether a string is a valid Java variable name in a **specific** Java version.

For example, [underscore became a reserved keyword starting from Java 9](https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8065599), so `isValidVariableNameInVersion("_", SourceVersion.RELEASE_9)` returns `false` while `isValidVariableNameInVersion("_", SourceVersion.RELEASE_8)` returns `true`.

**How it works**

[`SourceVersion.isIdentifier(CharSequence name)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/lang/model/SourceVersion.html#isIdentifier-java.lang.CharSequence-) checks whether  or not name is a syntactically valid identifier (simple name) or keyword in the latest source version. [`!SourceVersion.isKeyword(name)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/lang/model/SourceVersion.html#isKeyword-java.lang.CharSequence-) returns false for keywords. As a result, `SourceVersion.isIdentifier(name) && !SourceVersion.isKeyword(name)` returns true for valid indetifiers and only for them.

The same approach is used in the built-in method [`SourceVersion.isName(CharSequence name, SourceVersion version)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/lang/model/SourceVersion.html#isName-java.lang.CharSequence-) that checks whether name is a syntactically valid **qualified** name, which means that it will return `true` for strings like "apple.color":

```java
public static boolean isName(CharSequence name, SourceVersion version) {
    String id = name.toString();

    for(String s : id.split("\\.", -1)) {
        if (!isIdentifier(s) || isKeyword(s, version))
            return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

**Test**

```java
import org.junit.jupiter.api.Test;

import javax.lang.model.SourceVersion;

import static org.assertj.core.api.Assertions.assertThat;

public class ValidVariableNameTest {
    boolean isValidVariableName(CharSequence name) {
        return isValidVariableNameInVersion(name, SourceVersion.RELEASE_8);
    }

    boolean isValidVariableNameInVersion(CharSequence name, SourceVersion version) {
        return SourceVersion.isIdentifier(name) && !SourceVersion.isKeyword(name, version);
    }

    @Test
    void variableNamesCanBeginWithLetters() {
        assertThat(isValidVariableName("test")).isTrue();
        assertThat(isValidVariableName("e2")).isTrue();
        assertThat(isValidVariableName("w")).isTrue();
        assertThat(isValidVariableName("привет")).isTrue();
    }

    @Test
    void variableNamesCanBeginWithDollarSign() {
        assertThat(isValidVariableName("$test")).isTrue();
        assertThat(isValidVariableName("$e2")).isTrue();
        assertThat(isValidVariableName("$w")).isTrue();
        assertThat(isValidVariableName("$привет")).isTrue();
        assertThat(isValidVariableName("$")).isTrue();
        assertThat(isValidVariableName("$55")).isTrue();
    }

    @Test
    void variableNamesCanBeginWithUnderscore() {
        assertThat(isValidVariableName("_test")).isTrue();
        assertThat(isValidVariableName("_e2")).isTrue();
        assertThat(isValidVariableName("_w")).isTrue();
        assertThat(isValidVariableName("_привет")).isTrue();
        assertThat(isValidVariableName("_55")).isTrue();
    }

    @Test
    void variableNamesCannotContainCharactersThatAreNotLettersOrDigits() {
        assertThat(isValidVariableName("apple.color")).isFalse();
        assertThat(isValidVariableName("my var")).isFalse();
        assertThat(isValidVariableName(" ")).isFalse();
        assertThat(isValidVariableName("apple%color")).isFalse();
        assertThat(isValidVariableName("apple,color")).isFalse();
        assertThat(isValidVariableName(",applecolor")).isFalse();
    }

    @Test
    void variableNamesCannotStartWithDigit() {
        assertThat(isValidVariableName("2e")).isFalse();
        assertThat(isValidVariableName("5")).isFalse();
        assertThat(isValidVariableName("123test")).isFalse();
    }


    @Test
    void differentSourceVersionsAreHandledCorrectly() {
        assertThat(isValidVariableNameInVersion("_", SourceVersion.RELEASE_9)).isFalse();
        assertThat(isValidVariableNameInVersion("_", SourceVersion.RELEASE_8)).isTrue();

        assertThat(isValidVariableNameInVersion("enum", SourceVersion.RELEASE_9)).isFalse();
        assertThat(isValidVariableNameInVersion("enum", SourceVersion.RELEASE_4)).isTrue();
    }

    @Test
    void keywordsCannotBeUsedAsVariableNames() {
        assertThat(isValidVariableName("strictfp")).isFalse();
        assertThat(isValidVariableName("assert")).isFalse();
        assertThat(isValidVariableName("enum")).isFalse();

        // Modifiers
        assertThat(isValidVariableName("public")).isFalse();
        assertThat(isValidVariableName("protected")).isFalse();
        assertThat(isValidVariableName("private")).isFalse();

        assertThat(isValidVariableName("abstract")).isFalse();
        assertThat(isValidVariableName("static")).isFalse();
        assertThat(isValidVariableName("final")).isFalse();

        assertThat(isValidVariableName("transient")).isFalse();
        assertThat(isValidVariableName("volatile")).isFalse();
        assertThat(isValidVariableName("synchronized")).isFalse();

        assertThat(isValidVariableName("native")).isFalse();

        // Declarations
        assertThat(isValidVariableName("class")).isFalse();
        assertThat(isValidVariableName("interface")).isFalse();
        assertThat(isValidVariableName("extends")).isFalse();
        assertThat(isValidVariableName("package")).isFalse();
        assertThat(isValidVariableName("throws")).isFalse();
        assertThat(isValidVariableName("implements")).isFalse();

        // Primitive types and void
        assertThat(isValidVariableName("boolean")).isFalse();
        assertThat(isValidVariableName("byte")).isFalse();
        assertThat(isValidVariableName("char")).isFalse();
        assertThat(isValidVariableName("short")).isFalse();
        assertThat(isValidVariableName("int")).isFalse();
        assertThat(isValidVariableName("long")).isFalse();
        assertThat(isValidVariableName("float")).isFalse();
        assertThat(isValidVariableName("double")).isFalse();
        assertThat(isValidVariableName("void")).isFalse();

        // Control flow
        assertThat(isValidVariableName("if")).isFalse();
        assertThat(isValidVariableName("else")).isFalse();

        assertThat(isValidVariableName("try")).isFalse();
        assertThat(isValidVariableName("catch")).isFalse();
        assertThat(isValidVariableName("finally")).isFalse();

        assertThat(isValidVariableName("do")).isFalse();
        assertThat(isValidVariableName("while")).isFalse();
        assertThat(isValidVariableName("for")).isFalse();
        assertThat(isValidVariableName("continue")).isFalse();

        assertThat(isValidVariableName("switch")).isFalse();
        assertThat(isValidVariableName("case")).isFalse();
        assertThat(isValidVariableName("default")).isFalse();
        assertThat(isValidVariableName("break")).isFalse();
        assertThat(isValidVariableName("throw")).isFalse();

        assertThat(isValidVariableName("return")).isFalse();

        // Other keywords
        assertThat(isValidVariableName("this")).isFalse();
        assertThat(isValidVariableName("new")).isFalse();
        assertThat(isValidVariableName("super")).isFalse();
        assertThat(isValidVariableName("import")).isFalse();
        assertThat(isValidVariableName("instanceof")).isFalse();

        // Reserved keywords
        assertThat(isValidVariableName("goto")).isFalse();
        assertThat(isValidVariableName("const")).isFalse();
    }

    @Test
    void literalsCannotBeUsedAsVariableNames() {
        assertThat(isValidVariableName("null")).isFalse();
        assertThat(isValidVariableName("true")).isFalse();
        assertThat(isValidVariableName("false")).isFalse();
    }
}
```

Comment: wouldn't the SourceVersion.isIdentifier() method be more adequate here?

Comment: Agree, looks that "SourceVersion.isIdentifier()" behaves much better, for string such as "my.var"

Comment: @ChristopheMoine @Sebastian thanks a lot for pointing out a bug in my answer. I've fixed it and significantly expanded the answer. Note, that `SourceVersion.isIdentifier()` alone cannot be used to check whether a string is a valid Java variable because it returns `true` for keywords like `null`, `int`, `true`, `false`, that cannot be used as Java variable names