# Using a dot in a string name

Tags: java

The following line of code will not compile:

```
String 89.9 = new String("Hot 89.9");
```

It gives the following errors:

```
src/mainPackage/Userinterface.java:73: error: ';' expected
        String Hot89.9 = new String("Hot 89.9");
                    ^

src/mainPackage/Userinterface.java:73: error: invalid method declaration; return type required
        String Hot89.9 = new String("Hot 89.9");
                             ^

src/mainPackage/Userinterface.java:73: error: illegal start of type
        String Hot89.9 = new String("Hot 89.9");
```

Am I doing something wrong when I am creating my string?

Comment: It is not allowed to have a dot in variable names in java.

Comment: here `String 89.9` instead of `89.9` there must be some variable name. you must read the variable naming convention rule.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/11774170/829571

Comment: Variable naming rules: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/variables.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- You cannot create a variable name starting with numeric's.
- You cannot use period with in the variable name in Java.

Try to change it to something else

```
String hot89_9= new String("Hot 89.9");
```

Period have a special meaning in Java (dot operator)

Answer (score 2):

Variable name cannot begin with a number, or contain '.' in it.

```
String s89_9 = new String("Hot 89.9");
```

Comment: variable name must not contain '.`(dot)

Answer (score 0):

You cannot have a period (dot) in a variable name

If you really want you can try this

```
String s89_9 = new String("Hot 89.9");
```

Comment: @TheLostMind yes why?

Comment: 89_99 is not valid variable name

Comment: @DavidPilkington because it does not compile - variable names cannot start with a numer.

Comment: @DavidPilkington - I suggest you try it again. I don't think it will compile.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you try to use a period (`.`) in a variable name. That is **NOT** allowed.

Answer (score 0):

You can't have a variable name with "." and the best practice to declare a variable name is to use lower case for the first character

Answer (score 0):

U cannot use dot (".") for naming in Java. Dot is for methods and properties:

```
Integer.valueOf("123");
String name = worger.name;
```

Answer (score 0):

No, a dot is not allowed in an identifier name. Only special characters you can use is a $ and _

Checkout the naming rules for identifiers [here](http://www.slideshare.net/JavaWithUs/java-rules-for-naming-identifiers-22375868)

Answer (score 0):

You cannot use .(dot) in a variable name. Only alphanumeric characters and _ (underscore) are allowed in the variable name.

Answer (score 0):

[http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/variables.html][1]

http://www.c4learn.com/java/java-variable-naming-rules/

Have a look at these links...

Answer (score 0):

A small note, creating a new String object is worse in perfomance as opposed to just directly giving in the string.