# Which of these are valid variable names?

Tags: java, netbeans

This is a question from a Java test I took at University

I. publicProtected

II. $_

III. _identi#ficador

I've. Protected

I'd say I, II, and I've are correct. What is the correct answer for this?

Source of the question in spanish: Teniendo la siguiente lista de identificadores de variables, ¿Cuál (es) es (son) válido (s)?

Comment: Why didn't you try it? (and yes, you're correct)

Comment: I tried it, but my teacher said it's I and II. What should I tell my teacher?

Comment: Tell your teacher to read the Java Language Spec, which clearly describes what names are valid variable names.  Or show him/her a Java program that works correctly, and contains `Protected` as a variable name.

Comment: @VilchesFelipe Maybe he mistook it for the `protected` keyword. Tell him that keywords are case-sensitive.

Comment: It's possible this is one of the teachers who gets "valid" mixed up with "accepted" and wanted everyone to say IV was invalid because typical JAVA code doesn't capitalize the first letter.

Comment: Why is this so heavily downvoted? I seems like a reasonable question to me.

Comment: They aren't downvoting the question, they are downvoting my teacher.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Legal identifiers in Java](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11774099/legal-identifiers-in-java)

Comment: They're probably downvoting it because they feel that you could have tried for yourself, to see which variable names actually "work".  Or possibly because the answer is so readily available in the JLS.  Note that Java is not like HTML - if you write invalid Java, it simply won't compile; whereas browsers tend to do their best to display HTML even if it's invalid.  So "does this actually work" is a good way to see whether you're dealing with valid Java or not.

Answer (score 5):

From the java documentation:

> Variable names are case-sensitive. A variable's name can be any legal
>   identifier — **an unlimited-length sequence of Unicode letters and
>   digits, beginning with a letter, the dollar sign "$", or the
>   underscore character "*"***. The convention, however, is to always begin
>   your variable names with a letter, not "$" or "". Additionally, the
>   dollar sign character, by convention, is never used at all. You may
>   find some situations where auto-generated names will contain the
>   dollar sign, but your variable names should always avoid using it. A
>   similar convention exists for the underscore character; while it's
>   technically legal to begin your variable's name with "_", this
>   practice is discouraged. White space is not permitted. **Subsequent
>   characters may be letters, digits, dollar signs, or underscore
>   characters**. Conventions (and common sense) apply to this rule as well.
>   When choosing a name for your variables, use full words instead of
>   cryptic abbreviations. Doing so will make your code easier to read and
>   understand. In many cases it will also make your code
>   self-documenting; fields named cadence, speed, and gear, for example,
>   are much more intuitive than abbreviated versions, such as s, c, and
>   g. Also keep in mind that the name you choose must not be a keyword or
>   reserved word.

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/variables.html

In short: yes, you're right. You can use underscores, dollarsigns, and characters to start a variable name. After the first letter of the variable name, you can also use numbers. Note that using dollar signs is generally not good practice.

From your comment, you said that your teacher rejected "II". Under your question, II is perfectly fine (try it, it will run). However, if the question on your test asked which are "good" variable names, or which variable names follow common practice, then II would be eliminated as explained in the quotation above. One reason for this is that dollar signs do not make readable variable names; they're included because internally Java makes variables that use the dollar sign.

[What is the meaning of $ in a variable name?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7484210/what-is-the-meaning-of-in-a-variable-name)

As pointed out in the comments, IV is not a good name either, since the lower case version "protected" is a reserved keyword. With syntax highlighting, you probably wouldn't get the two confused, but using keyword-variations as variable names is certainly one way to confuse future readers

Comment: No, my teacher rejected Protected (IV). I and II were considered correct during the test revision

Comment: Well there's some ambiguity in the term "valid". Valid in terms of Java specification is unambiguous - put it in code, run the code, show her the output, no more question. There's not much debating it, the code will compile and run. "Valid" in her classroom and valid as an answer on that quiz are different, and I can't speak for those, she's free to define them as she pleases :) I'm fairly certain there's no versioning issues here, though I've never used Java 1.1 so I can't say for sure

Comment: Yeah, there are no version issues.  The answer to this question is the same in every version of Java - the teacher is simply wrong.  (I taught a Java 1.0 course back in the '90s).  Unfortunately, the question of how to deal appropriately with a teacher when they make mistakes is beyond the scope of Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 0):

Private protected public are reserved or keywords in java.. Use _ or to use that those words.. example 
        int  public_x;
        int protected_x;
        String private_s;

Comment: `Private` is not a reserved word.

Comment: Yes, `private` is a reserved word.  `Private` is not.

Comment: omg... u r right my bad...... The first word in a line has to be capitalized ahahahaa..