# In Java compiler，which type can be defined as identifier ( ID ) or Keyword (reserved word)?

Tags: java, printing, keyword, identifier

I have a simple question:
In Java Compiler, Which type of method or variables can be defined as identifier (ID) or Keyword (reserved word)?

For following example, ID should be : `add`, `main`, `a`, `b`, `c`, `Test1`, What about `print`, is `print` an ID or keyword?

Example:

```
public class Test1 {
    public static int add(int a, int b) {
        return a + b;
    }
    public static void main() {
        int c;
        int a = 5;
        c = add(a, 10);
        if (c > 10)
            print("c = " + -c);
        else
            print(c);
        print("Hello World");
    }
}
```

Comment: `print` has to be defined as method (otherwise your program would not compile), so for java it would be an ID. Details to keywords can be found in the [Java Language Specification](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/).

Comment: The Java keywords are listed in the [JLS #3.9](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-3.html#jls-3.9).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An **identifier** is a word used by a programmer to name a *variable, method, class, or label*.

```
        // Test1 is a class name identifier 
        public class Test1 {
                public static int add(int a, int b) { // add is identifier for a method
                      return a + b; 
                 }  

                public static void main() {
                    int c; // c is identifier for a variable
                    int a = 5;
                    c = add(a, 10);
                    if (c > 10)
                         print("c = " + -c);
                    else
                        print(c);
                    print("Hello World");
                 } 
        }
```

You `cannot use` any of the `Keywords as identifiers` in your java programs

`print` in your above program is not a `Keyword`, you can use print as a `identifier`

After using print as a identifier your code looks like this.

```
//Test1 is a class name identifier 
public class Test1 {
    // add is identifier for a method
    public static int add(int a, int b) {
    return a + b;
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    int c; // c is identifier for a variable
    int a = 5;
    c = add(a, 10);
    if (c > 10)
        print("c = " + -c); // c is a String
    else
        print(c); // c is a int
    print("Hello World"); // Hello World is a String
}

/**
 * Method Overriding
 */
private static void print(int c) {
    System.out.println("In Integer Print Method "+c);
}

private static void print(String string) {
    System.out.println("In String Print Method "+string);
}

}
```

**Also Refer :**

- [Check Legal Identifiers in java @Peter Lawrey](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11774099/legal-identifiers-in-java/#answer-11774161)
- [List of Keywords and Reserved Words in java](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/_keywords.html)

Comment: What If my format is System.out.print(c) without any method overriding,
is print an ID or keyword?

Comment: @user2871337 In `System.out.print(c)` the `System` class contains several useful class fields and methods.It cannot be instantiated. System Class are used as standard input, standard output, and error output streams; `out` is a `PrintStream` class where you will be having `print`as a method `public void print(char c) {
        write(String.valueOf(c));
    }` which makes clear that `print is a ID not a Keyword`.

Comment: @user2871337 Refer [PrintStream Class](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/PrintStream.html) for better understanding.

Comment: Yes, I finally can distinguish them. Thanks!!

Comment: @user2871337 Please, don't misuse `SO` by posting same questions! It effects in getting `downvoted` and results in losing `credits`. [`Duplicate of above comment`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29823840/in-java-compiler-the-print-in-system-out-print-can-be-defined-as-identifier-or-k) Some times we wont get reply back as-soon-as we think. Be patient and try to make you question more understandable and give more examples so that it can be addressed quickly. Consider this as a suggestion from a `friend`. Hope you rate with good credits and avoid mistakes :)

Answer (score 0):

The Java keywords are part of the language, and are documented in the [Java Language](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/_keywords.html). You cannot use a keyword as an identifier . `const` and `goto` are reserved keywords, but not implemented. `true`, `false`, and `null` are literals; you still cannot use them as identifiers but they are not keywords.

From the linked Java tutorial, the keywords are

- abstract
- continue
- for
- new
- switch
- assert<sup>3</sup>
- default
- goto<sup>1</sup>
- package
- synchronized
- boolean
- do
- if
- private
- this
- break
- double
- implements
- protected
- throw
- byte
- else
- import
- public
- throws
- case
- enum<sup>4</sup>
- instanceof
- return
- transient
- catch
- extends
- int
- short
- try
- char
- final
- interface
- static
- void
- class
- finally
- long
- strictfp<sup>2</sup>
- volatile
- const<sup>1</sup>
- float
- native
- super
- while

<sup>1</sup>not used

<sup>2</sup>added in 1.2

<sup>3</sup>added in 1.4

<sup>4</sup>added in 5.0