# In Java compiler，The print in System.out.print can be defined as identifier or Keyword?

Tags: methods, keyword, lex, identifier

I have studied about java which have listed 50 Java keywords. There is a homework of Lex, the goal is to recognize the word is keywords, IDs, symbols, operators. But there is one more little problem is the code below, is `print` in `System.out.print()` an ID or keyword?

```
 public class HelloWorld {
    public static int add(int a, int b) {
    return a + b;
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int c;
        int a = 5;
        c = add(a, 10);
        if (c > 10)
            System.out.print("c = " + -c);
        else
            System.out.print(c);
        System.out.print("Hello World");
        }
}
```

Comment: If you mean `c` then its an identifier. `print()` is a method.

Comment: Sorry for your misunderstand~ I want to ask "print" in System.out.print, is it keyword or ID ? I have confused..

Comment: "print" is a method not a keyword. @user2871337

Comment: Sorry for the duplicate asking...I just afraid nobody would see it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

print is the name of a method in the java.io.PrintStream class, hence an ID. Keywords are those which generally turn blue or another colour when you type them in most IDEs.

For more information: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/index.html

Comment: Good!! Now I got it. Thanks：）

Answer (score 1):

**System** is a final class from `java.lang package`.
**out** is the reference of `PrintStream` class and a static member of `System` class.
**print** is a method of `PrintStream` class.

```
//the System class belongs to java.lang package
class System {
  public static final PrintStream out;
  //...
}

//the Prinstream class belongs to java.io package
class PrintStream{
public void print();
//...
}
```

Have a look at this too.. https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/System.html

Comment: Good!! Now I got it. Thanks：）