# regex exclude a character not work

Tags: java, regex

i want to get class  name from java file .for example

```
class Mango {
```

now i want to get `mango` as class name.

this is the regex i used

```
\s*class\s+(\S+)
```

it works and i captured the class name .the problem is if clasname has no spaces between classname and closing curly bracket i get name as `mango{`

like below one.

```
class Mango{
```

so i want to exclude `{` from group.so i modyfy to following

```
\s*class\s+(\S+|[^{])
```

but it doesn't work and still capture classname with closing bracket. how can i get only class name .

[image]

Answer (score 4):

try with this regex:

```
class\s+([\w$]+)
```

`\w` - is a word character (a-zA-Z0-9_)

This regex will capture only allowed characters for class names. However if we assume that coder used valid characters, you can also try:

```
(?<=class\s)\s*(.+?)(?=\s*\{)
```

[DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/nT4tH2/1)

which is:

- `(?<=class\s)` - positive lookbehind for word class and whitespace,
- `\s*(.+?)` - zero or more whitespaces, and a one or more character,
- `(?=\s*\{)` - positive lookahead for whitspace(s) and curly bracket
  `{`

to directly get class name. This regex allow all characters, however it could be useful if coder would use one of rarely used [characters](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11774161/4607417) allowed in Java names.

Comment: Even better would be a regex which matches the Java identifier rules, IIRC: `class\s+([a-zA-Z_]\w*)` (identifiers start with an alphabetic or underscore character and follow with zero or more alphanumerics (or underscore). (May better better using Unicode character classes: I cannot recall if Java identifiers can use characters beyond ASCII).

Comment: Problem with `\w` is that it will not match all possible characters which can be used in class name like `$`.

Comment: @m.cekiera thanks but `(?<=class\s)\s*(.+)(?=\s+\{)` doesn't capture mango from `class mango{`

Comment: @whiletrue sorry, my obvius mistake, I assumed that there would be always space after name, I updated answer

Answer (score 3):

To accept only proper characters which can be used as names of classes or variables we may want to use method [`Character.isJavaIdentifierPart`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Character.html#isJavaIdentifierPart-char-), which can be referred via `\p{javaJavaIdentifierPart}` as explained in [Pattern class documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html) (emphasis mine):

> Categories that behave like the `java.lang.Character boolean isMethodName` methods (except for the deprecated ones) are available through the same `\p{property}` syntax where the specified `property` has the name `javaMethodName`.

Demo:

```
String text = "class Mango{";

Pattern p = Pattern.compile("\\s*class\\s+(\\p{javaJavaIdentifierPart}+)");
Matcher m = p.matcher(text);

if (m.find()){
    System.out.println(m.group(1));
}else{
    System.out.println("no match found");
}
```

Output: `Mango`

---

If you are not going to use this regex in Java engine, then you can use `[^\s{]` instead of `\S` like

```
\s*class\s+([^\s{]+)
```

It will accept any character except whitespaces and `{`.

Comment: did you mean like this ?? `\s*class\s+([^\s{]+|[^{])`

Comment: @whiletrue Updated answer again to include `\p{javaJavaIdentifierPart}` which seems best tool in Java's regex to handle this case.

Answer (score 2):

Not sure what the question is: do you want an explanation for (a) why your approach does not work or would you like to know (b) what a correct regex for this problem looks like?

If it's the latter, other answers and comments have provided some correct expressions. If it's the former, then consider what

```
(\S+|[^{])
```

actually matches. What this basically says is: *match everything that is not a whitespace **or** is not a left curly bracket*. Note the "or" in that sentence.

The reason your expression still matches the `{` after "Mango" is that it satisfies the first part of the sentence: a `{` is not a whitespace, so your regex matches. The same argument applies to the space between "Mango" and the `{`: it satisfies the "not a left curly bracket" part, and thus is matched as well.

What you want is an expression that encodes: *match everything that is not a whitespace **and** is not a left curly bracket*. As mentioned above, other answers/comments to this question show examples on how to achieve this.