# How do I call a public static void that is in a different class.

Tags: java, class, static-methods

I have 2 classes, MainActivity and MainGame. If I have a public static void in MainActivity, and one in MainGame. How would I execute the one in MainGame from MainActivity?

For example, I have this:

Main Activity:

```
public static void 1()
{
2();
}
```

Main Game:

```
public static void 2()
{
//blah blah blah
}
```

Comment: ClassName.methodName, though "2" is not a valid method name.

Comment: To understand what are all the valid characters allowed for Java method name. Check out [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-3.html#jls-3.8) or [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10211135/java-valid-character-for-method-name).

Comment: What is the relation of this question with `Android`, it is general.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

2 isn't a valid method name I think, but if it were you'd just do:

```
MainActivity.2();
```

but let's say it isn't and you called it two instead, then maybe you're looking for

```
public class MainGame {
    public static void one() {
        System.out.println("called one()");
    }
}

public class MainActivity {

    public static void two() {
        MainGame.one();
    }

}
```

Comment: 2 was basically just what I put there to try to make it easier to understand, but yeah, that worked, thanks a lot!

Comment: Great. Hopefully you're all set now.

Answer (score 1):

> In Java All Names must start with a '_' or alphabet.

So, we can take the method names `1` as `_1` and `2` as `_2`.

The syntax for calling `static` methods in other classes is `ClassName.MethodName(arguments)`.
So, in this case you would change the code as follows:

```
class MainActivity{
public static void _1()
{
MainGame._2();
}
}
class MainGame{
public static void _2()
{
//blah blah blah
}
}
```